# Algebraic curve over rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Can you give a reference about algebraic curve over rings $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$?
I'm very interested in analogy Hasse-Weil theorem, R-R theorem...

Thank you.

Comment: Related question with interesting answers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/95408/elliptic-curves-over-rings

Comment: @minar Cool, thank you!